# How can I Iterate over a nested JS object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `useState` and `axios` to perform API call and GET response and passing it to Component to render it.

```js
const [state,setState] = useState([]);
const getCurrData = () => {
  axios.get('working api endpoint url').then(res => setState(res.data))   
}
```

Now using that response I'm passing it to the component

```
<KlineInfo myPasser={state} />
```

My `KlineInfo` component content is this:

```
import React from 'react'
    
const KlineInfo = (myPasser) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log('Mapping')}
      {Object.entries(myPasser)
         .map( ([key, value]) => `My key is ${key} and my value is ${value}` )
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default KlineInfo
```

Console log output is:

```
> "['My key is myPasser and my value is [object Object]']"
```

Now, my problem:

The content I get in the `KlineInfo` component is below:

```js
{
  myPasser: {
    retCode: 0,
    retMsg: "OK",
    result: {
      symbol: "KORN",
      category: "look",
      list: [
        ["1694444820000", "25125.5", "25166.5", "25119.5", "25159.5", "1096706", "43.63253731"],
        ["1694444760000", "25067", "25125.5", "25053", "25125.5", "760836", "30.32376935"],
        ["1694444700000", "25110", "25126.5", "25067", "25067", "1785068", "71.11550939"],
      ],
    },
    retExtInfo: {},
    time: 1694444852507,
  },
}
```

How do I loop over the properties to get to myPasser-> result-> list to be able to:

1. Print out single list elements `[ ...],[...]` and also
2. Loop over individual elements of each list to store them in file and / or database?

In this case simple:

```
Object.entries(myPasser).map( ([key, value]) => `${key} ${value}`)
```

is not enough.

Comment: Important technical note: you are _not_ working with JSON. You're working with a normal, plain JS object. Just because the server sends a JSON string as response does not mean you're working with that string data, axios already turned it into normal JS object as part of the response handling. Also note that JS doesn't have "dict"s (that's Python) it only has objects with key/value properties, so remember to use the names used by the programming language you're working in.

Comment: What do you mean by `store then in file and / or database?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` is the Object itself, so you can't render that as is.

You should add a second `map()` inside your code so you can loop over `value.result.list.map` to render each `list`:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState(
        {
            "myPasser": {
                "retCode":0,
                "retMsg":"OK",
                "result":{
                    "symbol":"KORN",
                    "category":"look",
                    "list": [
                        ["1694444820000","25125.5","25166.5","25119.5","25159.5","1096706","43.63253731"],
                        ["1694444760000","25067","25125.5","25053","25125.5","760836","30.32376935"],
                        ["1694444700000","25110","25126.5","25067","25067","1785068","71.11550939"]
                    ]
                },
                "retExtInfo":{},
                "time":1694444852507
            }
        }
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            {Object.entries(state).map( ([key, value]) => (
              <div>
                  <em>{key}</em>
                  {value.result.list.map(ll => <pre>{ll}</pre>)}
              </div>)) }
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: When I'm adding your code  {Object.entries(myPasser).map( ([key, value]) => (
              <div>
                  <em>{key}</em>
                  {value.result.list.map(ll => <pre>{ll}</pre>)}
              </div>)) }  ---- I'm getting  "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')"

Comment: Check your network tab. Does the api return the correct data with the same structure?

Comment: Network shows that correct data in correct format is returned. Had to add value?.result?.list.map(ll => (... - so the questions mark '?' for property value nd result and it's working. Not sure why however.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
myPasser.myPasser.result.list.forEach(list => console.log(list))
```

Insert whatever logic you need inside the forEach function. For example, to iterate over the inner elements and operate on them:

```
myPasser.myPasser.result.list.forEach(
  list => list.forEach(x => myDatabaseStorageFunction(x)))
```